# How would I structure this url functionality in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rest

What I'm trying to do in Wordpress is import movie data from the movie database API, and display it inside a wordpress site. I'm just having trouble figuring out what would be the best way to set this up in the backend with a clean url structure.

I created a template file, and its going to have a GET variable with the movies title in it. I would want my domain to look like

mydomain.com/movie/TITLEGOESHERE

how could i set this up through wordpress, so the page I created works that way.

This would not be pulling post data from inside the wordpress. Would htaccess work here?

EDIT: 
The way im thinking of it right now with a dirty url is, mydomain.com/pagewithAPIcode/?movie=MOVIETITLE, that way I can get the MOVIE TITLE as a GET variable, and then pass it to the api to grab the external movie info. And then with htaccess, rewrite it so it looks nicer

Comment: I thnik the best (and natural) solution would be to create a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) `movie`. The link structure will be what you expect, the `movie` posts will be separated from other types types like `page` or `post` (news). If you don't want to add a new custom post type, you can add the text `movie` as a [prefix to links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332921/custom-permalink-structure-with-a-prefix-just-for-posts) for `page` or `post` post type.

Comment: the way im thinking of it right now with a dirty url is, mydomain.com/pagewithAPIcode/?movie=MOVIETITLE, that way I can get the MOVIE TITLE as a GET variable, and then pass it to the api to grab the external movie info. And then with htaccess, rewrite it so it looks nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, a query variable `mvtitle` is added in which the movie title will be available. A rewrite rule is also created which for addresses matching the `movie/{some-title}` scheme displays the page `movie` (post type `page`). To read value of the `mvtitle` use [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) function.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'so59386348_query_vars' );
add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'so59386348_page_rewrites' );

function so59386348_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = "mvtitle";
    return $vars;
}
function so59386348_page_rewrites( $rewrite_rules )
{
    $page_slug = 'movie';
    $rewrite_rules["$page_slug/([^/]+){1}/?$"] = 'index.php?pagename='.$page_slug.'&post_type=page&mvtitle=$matches[1]';
    return $rewrite_rules;
}
```

```
$title = get_query_var( 'mvtitle', FALSE );
echo 'Movie title: ' . $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below instructions:

1. Log in to your WordPress website.

   - When you're logged in, you will be in your 'Dashboard'.
2. Click on 'Settings'.

   - On the left-hand side, you will see a menu. In that menu, click on 'Settings'.
3. Click on 'Permalinks'.

   - The 'Settings' menu will expand providing you additional options. Click on 'Permalinks'.

[image]

4. Select 'Post name'.

   [image]
5. Click 'Save changes'.

I hope it would help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to edit for all posts, its a large site, Im building just one small part of it, which is completely independent from the rest of the site. There will be no posts stored on wordpress itself, all the data is being grabbed from the third party movie API. and i need to have the movie title in my url, to grab it from the external source.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open dashboard
2. Search for settings
3. Click to permalinks in settings
4. Look for Permalinks common settings
5. in Custom structure use the url like %category%/%postname% and save

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to edit for all posts, its a large site, Im building just one small part of it, which is completely independent from the rest of the site. There will be no posts stored on wordpress itself, all the data is being grabbed from the third party movie API. and i need to have the movie title in my url, to grab it from the external source.

Answer (score 0):

First of all open the admin panel, Go to `settings->permalinks` and in the custom settings, change the custom structure such as:

```
%custom_name%/%postname%
```

You can change the custom name with category or any other static name you want.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to edit for all posts, its a large site, Im building just one small part of it, which is completely independent from the rest of the site. There will be no posts stored on wordpress itself, all the data is being grabbed from the third party movie API. and i need to have the movie title in my url, to grab it from the external source.